# What is the meaning of the del operator in this equation?

Tags: vectors, differentiation, mathematics

> $$\frac{\partial \left(\rho_m \vec{v}_m \right)}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \left(\rho_m \vec{v}_m\vec{v}_m \right) \\ = - \nabla P_m + \nabla \left(\mu_m \nabla \vec{v}_m \right) + \nabla \left(\alpha_p \rho_p \vec{v}_{dr,p}\vec{v}_{dr,p}\right) + \mu_0 \left(\vec{M} \nabla \right) \vec{B}$$

I am trying to find the $x$ and $y$ components of the momentum equation above. However, the position of the $\nabla$ operator in the last term confuses me. I have never seen such a thing before. What does it mean?

Comment: The answer I believe is definitely correct. Keep in mind though juxtaposing two vectors is also used in writing the dyadic tensor, which can either be written as $\textbf{ab}$ or $\textbf{a}\otimes \textbf{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you give more details about the equation but here is why

$$\vec{M} \nabla = \vec{M} \cdot \nabla = M_{x} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+M_{y} \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+M_{z} \frac{\partial }{\partial z}$$

Comment: So it's just a notational laziness? Ugh.

Comment: But one should keep in mind that $\vec{M} \nabla = \vec{M} \cdot \nabla \neq \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$

Comment: So bad, Notational laziness by process of elimination for the only remaining thing that makes sense.

Comment: M⃗ ∇=M⃗ ⋅∇≠∇⋅M⃗  Ah yes, that's the point I missed.